# MATLAB: converting cell of variables to cell of strings of variable names

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, character, cell

I have a cell of cells...

```
bigcell={smallcell1,smallcell2,smallcell3};
```

I'm using this in a for loop, running histograms on each smallcell and then saving the histogram as a jpg.

```
for i=1:length(bigcell)
    saveloc=char([stringversion(bigcell{i}),'.jpg']); ???
    saveloc=char([bigcell_strings{i},'.jpg']); ???
    hist([bigcell{i}])
    saveas(gcf,saveloc);
end
```

I'd like to name each histogram after the cell its representing (i.e. smallcell1.jpg, smallcell2.jpg, etc.). I could have an alternate cell of strings:

```
bigcell_strings={'smallcell1','smallcell2','smallcell3'};
```

but I have a ton of cells to run through and am trying to limit the carpel tunnel.

Is there a simple way to convert the bigcell to a set of strings or within the for loop to call the name of the smallcell as a string?

Thanks

Comment: You just need to create a cell array of the names. Once you assign them into `bigcell` there is no record of it's name

Comment: Why can't you use `saveloc= ['smallcell',num2str(i),'.jpg']);`

Comment: yea that's what I've been doing but in reality there's like 100 small cells so I was hoping there was some way around creating the array of names/strings

Answer (score 0):

Use `v=who('smallcell*');` to get the names of the small cells in the workspace.